# How to navigate to another view when i tapped a button in Sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, touch

I am developing a Sencha touch application Can anyone please tell me how to navigate to another view when i tapped a button, also have to send a value to the specified view.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to navigate from one view to another. Please look at the below link and read the accepted answer.

[How to switch a view container using Sencha Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585171/how-to-switch-a-view-container-using-sencha-touch)

You can also use Navigation view in Sencha to navigate from one to another:

http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/docs/Ext.navigation.View.1/viewer.html

And if you want to pass a value from one view to another. For example, you want to send the value from a text field to other page's HTML. You can write something like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('ID OF THE SECOND VIEW').setHtml(Ext.getCmp('ID OF THE TEXT FIELD ').getValue());
```

Comment: Thank you Geeniewanted...its working...I have a another question can you plz help me on that topic :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701189/not-navigating-to-the-leaf-node-when-i-tap-on-the-back-button-from-another-view