# Not navigating to the leaf node when I Tap on the back button from another view in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, touch

**I have a nested list in my app, on the leaf node i have a map button, I linked my  MapView to this button, its going well to the MapView, Now when I tap on the back button of the MapView I am getting a empty view instead of the leaf node with the following warnings**

WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`mainlist`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed

[WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`detailcard`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`.

[WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`description`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`.

**My Map Button**

onDetailButtonTap: function(activeItem) {
var record = this;

```
    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem((
                                Ext.create('App.view.MapView')),
                                {
                                    type: 'slide',
                                    direction:'left',
                                }).show();
},
```

**My Map View**

```
handler: function(){
                                //var x=document.getElementById("textt");
                                //alert(x.innerHTML);


                                Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem((
                                Ext.create('App.view.Sections')),
                                {
                                    type: 'slide',
                                    direction:'left',
                                }).show();

                            }
```

I need some serious help

Answer (score 0):

A common workaround for this issue is to use `itemId` instead of using `id` to query a component. With `itemId`, you can use Ext.ComponentQuery.query to make all queries.

Ext.getCmp('[ID OF THE COMPONENT]');

(Is equivalent to)

Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#[ITEMID OF YOUR COMPONENT]');

To dig in further on ComponentQuery, please follow the link:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Example:

You have a container/item with an `itemId` and an `id`. Like this,

```
items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                id: 'titleBar',
                itemId: 'barTitle',
                title: 'fooBar'
            },
```

So, if you just want to change the title using id, you will do this:

`Ext.getCmp('titleBar').setTitle('Title Changed using ID');` // 'titleBar' is the ID

You can do this same using `itemId` too. For that, you can write a line of code like this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#barTitle')[0].setTitle('Title Changed using ItemId');
```

// 'barTitle' is the ItemId

The above two ways do the same job. So, in your case, you can use the second way to fix the problem. In other words, you can use  `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` function with `itemId`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Geeniwanted: thank you very much...can you show me some examples, the documentation is quite hard for me to understand

Comment: @Geeniwanted: Thank you very much, its really helped me, but I solved in a different approach, I push the view in a container rather then to navigate to that view and get back to the DetailView...anyways thanks again. stay blessed :)

Comment: @Aamin: Great that you got it fixed! Happy Coding :)